# Using MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT with sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I am trying to get my head around using GROUP_CONCAT within MYSQL.

Basically I have the following table, table1:

id, field1, field2, active

I want to bring back 5 rows within the table but in random order. So I'm using this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY rand()) FROM table1 WHERE active=1
```

This behaves as I would expect. I then want to use the output to select the other columns (field1, field2) from the table and display the results.
So I've tried using:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY rand()) as id FROM table1 WHERE active=1
);
```

I expected something like the above to work but I cant figure out why it doesn't. It DOES bring back results but not all of them, (i.e.) my table contains 10 rows. 6 rows are set to active=1. Therefore I would expect 6 rows to be returned ... this isn't happening I may get 1,2 or 0.

Additionally if it helps I'd like to limit the number of results returned by the sub-query to 3 but adding LIMIT doesn't seem to have any affect on the results returned.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: some sample data maybe or a sqlfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  This will bring back 5 random active rows.

```
SELECT  *

FROM    table1

WHERE active=1

ORDER BY RAND()

LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you! realised that I was over complicating it with your answer. really appreciate the help

Comment: No problem.  The simplest solution is usually the best one.

Answer (score 0):

why not use this :

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY rand()) as randoms FROM table1 WHERE active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to build a query like this:

```
select *
from table1
where id in (1,2,3,4,5) -- Just an example
```

and you are trying to "fill" the in condition with a `group_concat()` result.

That's not the way to do it.

You only need to specify the subquery in the parenthesis:

```
select *
from table1
where id in (select id from table1 where active=1)
```

Notice some additional things:

- The `order by rand()`  is irrelevant, because the `in ()` will be evaluated regardless of the order of the values.
- In this particular scenario, I would recommend to use a `join` instead of `in`.

Using `join`:

```
select t1.*
from 
    table1 as t1
    inner join table1 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.active=1
```